# Select record according to column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as shown below, and I want to select `u_id` with type, but if there are more records for `u_id` then I want to get record that has `best` type, or if it's not there then `good` and so on, `best>good>worst` so far. I am only able to get first row for `u_id` that is returned.

```
u_id type
 1  best
 2  good
 3  worst
 2  best
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prioritize this with `row_number` and select one row per u_id.

```
select u_id,type 
from (
select u_id,type,
row_number() over(partition by u_id order by case when type='best' then 1 
                                                  when type='good' then 2
                                                  when type='worst' then 3 
                                                  else 4 end) as rn
from tablename
) t
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with type (n, type) as (values
    (1, 'best'),(2,'good'),(3,'worst')
)
select distinct on (u_id) u_id, type
from t inner join type using (type)
order by u_id, n
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the other answers are really good.  This is a variant on the `distinct on` version that doesn't require a `join`:

```
select distinct on (u_id) u_id, type
from t
order by u_id, array_position(array[('best'), ('good'), ('worst')], type)
```

Comment: I already used the "Accepted answer" method, but this looks easiest to understand to me.

Comment: I tried to do this approach because if I do the approach in accepted answer, it takes 60 times longer to get my data. But function array_position doesn't exists in postgreSQL